# why is this jQuery .animate call so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Hi All I have a pretty straight forward function

```
enableModule : function(moduleName){
        var module = $('div#'+moduleName);
        console.log('enabling '+moduleName);
        console.time('animate');
        module.animate({'opacity' : '1.0'}, 300, function(){console.timeEnd('animate');});
        module.find('.disabled_sheild').remove();
        module.removeClass('disabled');
        console.log('end of enable Module');
    }
```

The animation its self, the opacity change, is very fast but there is like a delay in calling it. the console.time() is reporting times of 2540MS and greater. I'm thinking it may be because the div#module is being animated along with its children? but this dosent make sense because I have another function "disableModule" which does the same thing in reverse and runs at a reasonable speed.

Here is the disable Module function, considerably more going on but returns times of about 242ms

```
disableModule : function(moduleName){
      $('div#'+moduleName+', div.'+moduleName).each(function(){
        var module = $(this);
        module.prepend('<div class="disabled_sheild"></div>');
        var sheild = module.find('.disabled_sheild');
        sheild.css({'position' : 'absolute', 'z-index' : '200'});
        sheild.width(module.width());
        sheild.height(module.height());
        jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i) {
            if($.browser.msie){
               //module.css("display","none");
               //if using ie give sheild a transparent background layout
            }else{
              console.time('animate');
              module.animate({'opacity' : '0.5'}, function(){ console.timeEnd('animate');});
            }
          });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some arduous troubleshooting i tracked it down to being an issue with the browser detection loop in the disable method:

```
  jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i) {
      if($.browser.msie){
         //module.css("display","none");
         //if using ie give sheild a transparent background layout
      }else{
        console.time('animate');
        module.animate({opacity : 0.5}, 200, function(){console.timeEnd('animate');});
      }
    });
```

Commenting this block out brought everything up to speed. I almost pulled my hair out after trying to optimize everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply re-ording them?

```
module.find('.disabled_sheild').remove();
module.removeClass('disabled');
module.animate({'opacity' : '1.0'}, 300, function(){console.timeEnd('animate');});
```

Animation happens asynchronously and the `find` and `remove` methods could be consuming resources  (especially since `find` walks the DOM tree) that could otherwise be used to for the animation.

Also, since you are dynamically creating the "disabled shield" in the `disable` method, you could save it off

```
module.data("disabledShield", module.prepend('<div class="disabled_sheild"></div>'));
```

and just use that reference in your `enable` method to avoid the DOM walk

```
module.data("disabledShield").remove();
module.removeClass('disabled');
module.animate({'opacity' : '1.0'}, 300, function(){console.timeEnd('animate');});
```

(See http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data for doc on `$.data`)